# How can I disable the Alt + F1 and Alt + F2 shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome

I can assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to any function I like in the keyboard configuration window, but it's not being used.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> is always 'dash home' and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is always 'run'.

Answer (score 30):

I sat with the same issue after upgrading to [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) and installing GNOME Shell. I tried to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> from wherever I could, to no avail.

As I was about to give up, I found this gist: https://gist.github.com/2402448

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]" # disable Alt+F1
```

**Credits go to [Jan Musinsky](https://gist.github.com/musinsky)**.

Comment: Indeed works for Alt-F1. I found the following way to list built-in keybindings: `for k in \`gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings\`; do echo $k = \`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings $k\`; done`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: This script shows <Alt>F2 but it doesn't show <Alt>F1.

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"
will clear `Super`+`S` also, which is default in Ubuntu 14.04, so be careful.

Comment: On 16.04 this is not enough. Solution by @andersoyvind works ok.

Comment: For `<Alt>F2` it seems to be set in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keywindings panel-run-dialog` in Ubuntu 20.04, and maybe later versions too.

Comment: For `GNOME Shell 41.4` (`gnome-shell --version`) clearing `panel-main-menu` no longer works, but this works:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.apps-menu apps-menu-toggle-menu "[]" # disable Alt+F1`

Answer (score 22):

With the Ubuntu [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) plugin installed, the musinsky gist snippet in the terminal wasn't enough.

Disable it using [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM):

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
ccsm
```

In section *"Desktop"* (third item on the left), click on *"Ubuntu Unity Plugin"*. In tab *"General"* (the default), click the edit pencil for *"Key to execute a command"* (the fourth item), blank out (delete) the content, and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

#### General tab

- Key to show the HUD - **disable**
- Key to execute a command - **disable**

#### Launcher tab

- Key to give keyboard focus to Launcher - **disable**

Comment: After using johanmynhard's method, this one did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It's worth noting that the "Unity Plugin" is in the desktop section of the CCSM utility. (true as of 8/2017)

Answer (score 6):

Although [johanmynhardt gave us the right answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts/128745#128745) for the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, he did not tell us what it was for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. With [the `for` loop as shown by Jesse Glick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts/128745#comment168794_128745) in a comment, I figured out the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> command. Like this to remove *both* keys:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]" # Disable Alt + F1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog "[]" # Disable Alt + F2
```

The way to find the valid keys (`panel-main-menu` an `panel-run-dialog` in the above examples) is to use the `list-keys` command line option of `gsettings`. Be ready to get a pretty long list.

The following are all the system defined keybindings for 20.04:

```
switch-group
begin-resize
switch-to-workspace-7
begin-move
move-to-side-w
move-to-corner-nw
move-to-workspace-10
move-to-workspace-6
move-to-workspace-right
always-on-top
toggle-maximized
move-to-workspace-left
switch-to-workspace-8
cycle-panels
move-to-workspace-11
lower
move-to-workspace-7
toggle-above
move-to-workspace-down
switch-panels
minimize
cycle-windows
switch-to-workspace-9
move-to-workspace-12
toggle-on-all-workspaces
switch-input-source
move-to-workspace-8
move-to-side-n
maximize-horizontally
activate-window-menu
set-spew-mark
switch-windows-backward
maximize-vertically
move-to-corner-sw
move-to-workspace-9
maximize
panel-main-menu
close
move-to-monitor-up
raise-or-lower
move-to-side-e
cycle-windows-backward
switch-to-workspace-1
move-to-monitor-right
switch-windows
panel-run-dialog
switch-panels-backward
unmaximize
switch-to-workspace-2
switch-applications
switch-to-workspace-last
move-to-workspace-1
move-to-corner-ne
switch-to-workspace-3
switch-to-workspace-up
move-to-side-s
show-desktop
move-to-center
move-to-workspace-2
switch-to-workspace-left
switch-to-workspace-right
raise
move-to-corner-se
switch-to-workspace-10
switch-to-workspace-4
toggle-shaded
cycle-group-backward
move-to-workspace-3
switch-to-workspace-down
cycle-panels-backward
move-to-monitor-left
switch-applications-backward
switch-to-workspace-11
switch-input-source-backward
switch-to-workspace-5
move-to-workspace-4
move-to-monitor-down
toggle-fullscreen
switch-to-workspace-6
switch-to-workspace-12
cycle-group
move-to-workspace-up
move-to-workspace-last
switch-group-backward
move-to-workspace-5
```

I still see a `panel-run-dialog` entry, I tested on my install and it worked as expected. After I ran the `set` command shown above, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> stopped working...

Comment: Please edit their answer to fix the that.

Comment: Disabling of `ALT + F2` not working in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @r0ei I tested on my 20.04.1 LTS install and it worked. You may have typed the command improperly or there is some extension you installed that ignores that gnome settings.

Comment: Also `begin-move` for `Alt+F7`

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 you can do it using the following command:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ keyboard-focus ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `gsettings`, we can use UI: `dconf-editor`
[image: screenshot]

The shortcuts are stored in `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/` path

Note how for `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/panel-main-menu` it says

```
DEPRECATED: This key is deprecated and ignored.
```

Indeed clearing Alt+F1 using either `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"` or by editing `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/panel-main-menu` in `dconf-editor` no longer works.

The setting now lives in `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/apps-menu/apps-menu-toggle-menu` in `dconf-editor`, changing it there to `[]` fixed it for me: [image: screenshot]

Or you can disable it using `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.apps-menu apps-menu-toggle-menu "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-run-dialog "[]"`

[image]