# How to disable Unity panel focus keyboard shortcut Alt + F1

Tags: unity, gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) and am trying to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut as I need it for [usage in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971221/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-python-console-and-the-editor-in-pycharm). I have already gone through *[How can I disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts)*. But it is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

The steps I have followed to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>:

1. I modified in dconf using the following command:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"
   ```
2. Logged out and logged in. Still <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> sends the keyboard focus to the Unity panel.
3. Restarted the machine. Still <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> sends the keyboard focus to the Unity panel.
4. Also verified that the configuration is still set using the following command

   ```
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu<br><br>*Output*<br>@as []
   ```

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. And I don't remember switching to Unity 2D. But I think I'm using Unity 2D from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in "Unity 2D" mode in the logon screen (metacity + unity-2d-shell). I tried all "known" stuff (gconf + dconf + gsettings) - it doesn't help.

But if switching to "Unity" mode in the logon screen (compiz + unity-shell) and tweaking in compizconfig-settings-manager- everything works fine!

So if you don't mind switching to "Unity" - then you will be fine :)