# Alt+F1 doesn't work

Tags: gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and gnome 3.14. I remap my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-4 keys to switching virtual desktops. All of them work besides <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: In my case F1 & F2 do not work and I have no other programs running.
F3 to F6 does go to cmd line OK but altF7 to return does not work.
I tried alt F1 and it put up the gnome login so I was able to come back and
complete this tale of woe.
I think someone has made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+F2 to go from the virtual console back to the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts/348607#348607) - to answer your query, the ALT-F1 is in use by something else already, you'll need to disable that (or think of a new number range for your desktops). On my xfce setup it's a right-click, I believe gnome uses it for activity centre?