# How do I find all key bindings in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, keyboard, compiz, shortcut-keys

The Ubuntu / Unity key bindings are interfering with Android Studio (IntelliJ) key bindings.  There is a partial list of key bindings to disable / reconfigure [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Keymap?focusedCommentId=57290671&#comment-57290671) in section 6.  It is missing Alt+F1 and I would like to see if there are any other Ubuntu key mappings that interfere with IntelliJ key mappings.

[This script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts) shows some Ubuntu / Unity key bindings, but it doesn't show that Alt+F1 is mapped.  The Alt+F1 mapping is shown in CompizConfig Manager.

Is there a way to show all key bindings in Ubuntu / Unity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to show all key bindings in Ubuntu / Unity is:

```
gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more
```

**However** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is not in there, meaning it's hard-coded in Unity *and cannot be changed*.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news*

Comment: Is there a way to get all of the hard-coded keybindings in Unity?

Comment: Would switching to gnome desktop solve this problem (not being able to find all key mappings) or does gnome have hidden key mappings too?

Comment: `grep --directories=recurse --ignore-case key linux-3.18.3/* | grep --ignore-case binding | wc`  gives as output  `918 lines 5189 words 91272 characters`.  You *really* don't want to download the kernel source and go look in there!  ;-)  I've looked for myself and it's just .... hopeless, so I switched my shortcuts to [Alt][F2], [Alt][F3], ... and left [Alt][F1] where is was!

Comment: Thanks.  I've posted my question about gnome versus Unity keybindings.  The Unity keybindings are interfering with a lot of applications and there has to be a way to manage all keybindings.  Another solution would be to allow whatever application has focus to have its keybindings override those in Ubuntu / Unity.

Comment: `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | more | grep -i '<Alt>F1'` to filter results containing `<Alt>F1`